# std::move для объекта, возвращенного функцией

Tags: c++, c++11

Имеется один файл main.cpp, в котором определены две глобальные функции getSomeResultFromSomeFunc(), processResult() и функция main():

```
std::string getSomeResultFromSomeFunc() {
    std::string result;
    if ( cond1 ) {
        // result = ...
    } else if ( cond2 ) {
        // result = ...
    }
    return result;
}

void processResult( const std::string& result ) {
    ...
}

int main(void) {
    std::string myResult = std::move( getSomeResultFromSomeFunc() );
    processResult( myResult );
    return 0;
}
```

Надо ли использовать std::move() при создании объекта myResult из другого объекта, который возвращается функцией? Чтобы вызывался конструктор перемещения для объекта myResult вместо конструктора копирования, так как это более быстрый способ создания объекта? Или компилятор автоматически вызовет конструктор перемещения вместо конструктора копирования, и использование std::move избыточно? И поэтому достаточно написать проще?

```
std::string myResult = getSomeResultFromSomeFunc();
```

или

```
std::string myResult( getSomeResultFromSomeFunc() );
```

Для user-defined типов легко проверить как ведет себя компилятор, а для типов из std никак не проверить?

Есть ли различия в использовании std::move для C++0x и C++11 в этом случае ?

Comment: Вообще-то де-факто у вас при вызове даже внутренняя переменная `result`создаваться не будет - сразу `myResult` будет использоваться. Никакого `move` не нужно в принципе.

Comment: Да, кстати, что вы понимаете под C++0x? C++03? так в нем семантики перемещения (и `move` соответственно) просто не было.

Comment: Да, move не нужно. С++0x - урезанная версия С++11, которую можно заюзать под Centos 6.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат, возвращенный функцией в вашем примере, является prvalue. Никакого смысла применять к нему `std::move` нет.

Своим `std::move` вы скорее заставите компилятор выполнить temporary materialization conversion там, где в ней никакой необходимости не было, а также подавите оптимизации (return value optimizations - RVO), искусственно "оторвав" инициализируемый объект `myResult` от его инициализатора `result`.

В самом лучшем случае успешного RVO в вашем коде не будет ни перемещения ни копирования - результат функции будет конструироваться прямо в вашем `myResult`.

Обратите внимание: https://godbolt.org/z/_4tnNh
Функция `getSomeResultFromSomeFunc` сразу получает на вход адрес получателя (`myResult`) в регистре `rdi` и всю дальнейшую работу ведет напрямую именно с `myResult`. Никакого локального `result` не создается вообще и никакого копирования/перемещения результата не выполняется.